# Remove Sidebar from Product Category Page | Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

My question is, how can i remove the sidebar only for particular Product category "Slug" and not for its child slugs.
If the url is like below - remove the side bar and make the page full width only for slugs "sanitaryware" and "closets" 
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/closets/

I dont want to remove the sidebar for all "Product Category" reason, i want the side bar to show up the grand-child slug"one-piece-closets":
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/closets/one-piece-closets

Code: that i am using in function.php - this is removing the side bar in all the product categories of the website.

```
  <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_sidebar hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
             */
            if (!is_product_category('sanitaryware')){
        do_action('storefront_sidebar');
}
?>
```

Comment: What theme are you currently using?

Comment: Storefront of wordpress

Comment: In the future, please simply edit your question in lieu of creating a new question where you are essentially asking the same thing.

Comment: @helgatheviking i have asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165017/remove-sidebar-from-specific-product-category-pages-not-all-wordpress-wooco?noredirect=1#comment52220269_32165017

Comment: I know. That's my point. Don't re-ask the same question. Edit your closed question and then we'll re-open it.

Comment: @helgatheviking i have changed my question above also deleted the other question, now can you please re-open and suggest and answer to the question as this is imporatant?

Comment: Much appreciated. I've voted to re-open it now that it has been re-worded. It doesn't seem like I have enough power on my own. Do note that for really important things (that you need right away) you may want to consider hiring a developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your desire to hide the sidebar on top-level categories and their immediate children, we will need a system for determining the hierarchical "depth" of any term archive. Similar to how people often get the "top-level" parent term we can do a `while` loop of getting a term's term object and checking for the term's parent. In our case instead of returning the top-level parent, we'll just keep a count and return that.

```
/**
* Returns depth level of product category
*
* @param    string      $catid  Product category ID to be checked
* @return   string      $depth  how many categories deep is this term in the hierarchy
*/
function so_32165017_get_product_cat_depth($catid) {
    $depth = 0;
    while ($catid) {
        $cat = get_term_by('id', $catid, 'product_cat'); // get the object for the catid
        if( $cat->parent > 0 ){
            $depth++;
        }
        $catid = $cat->parent; // assign parent ID (if exists) to $catid
        // the while loop will continue whilst there is a $catid
    }
    return $depth;
}
```

Now that we have something we can use as a condition we can conditionally remove the WooCommerce sidebar:

```
/**
* Hide the sidebar for items 2 levels deep or more
*/
function so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar(){
    if( is_product_category()){
        $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        if( so_32165017_get_product_cat_depth( $t_id ) < 2 ){
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
            // could be theme specific ex: Storefront
            remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar' );
```

**Edit/Update**

If you also want to add a custom body class to make the sidebar-less pages easier to style then I believe you can remove the actions in question from the `body_class` filter at the same time you are actually filtering the body class.

```
/**
* Hide the sidebar for items 2 levels deep or more
*/
function so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar( $class ){
    if( function_exists('is_product_category') && is_product_category() ){
        $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        if( so_32165017_get_product_cat_depth( $t_id ) < 2 ){
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
            // could be theme specific ex: Storefront
            remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
            // add a custom body class
            $class[] = 'full-width';
        }
    }
    return $class;
}
add_action( 'body_class', 'so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar' );
```

Comment: The above worked perfect to me in removing the sidebar for the first and 2nd Slug considering their depth.. Worked perfect. however, it does not answer the 2nd part of the request, which is making these pages full width. if i need to add a class to give only these pages a different style..where would i add a new style and how to map this style to those particular pages which we have changed using your code in the your answer mentioned abo.ve

Comment: can this be used to achive a different class or is there any changes needed in this code `// Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter( 'body_class', 'product_categories' );
function product_categories( $classes ) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    if (is_product_category('sanitaryware') && is_product_category('Faucet')) {
        $classes[] = 'product-category';
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make a custom template and prevent the sidebar from rendering if a Product Category page is being viewed. Following the upgrade-safe suggestions from the [Woocommerce docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) you should:

1) Go to the **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/** directory and copy the **`archive-product.php`** file

2) Create a **woocommerce** directory in your theme directory (e.g. wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce)

3) Create a copy of `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` and put place it in **wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/** and name the file **`archive-product.php`**

4) Look near the bottom of your new custom file and find:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
```

5) Replace that line of code with:

```
if (!is_product_category('sanitaryware') && !is_product_category('Faucet')) {
   do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
}
```

6) To make the Product Category page content be full-width you could add a class called `product-category` to the `<body>` of these pages using a filter.

To add this new class, insert this code in your **functions.php** file:

```
// Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter( 'body_class', 'product_categories' );
function product_categories( $classes ) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    if (is_product_category('sanitaryware') && is_product_category('Faucet')) {
        $classes[] = 'product-category';
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

7) Then in your theme's stylesheet you could target the Product Category pages using this CSS selector:

```
body.product-category { /* place Product Category page specific CSS here */ }
```

Since I don't know the specifics of your theme, I can't tell you the HTML elements you'd want to target to set 100% width to, but if the page content was in something like `<div id="content">` you could set the CSS like so:

```
body.product-category #content { 
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: The above code does not remove the sidebar. I missed to check, before asking the question. I have two paces where i am seeing the side bar:  1) Product Catalog Page, where i have the list of products with Side bar used as filter - here i need the side bar (But the problem is this page is also Product category). 2) The Product Category where i have summary of products with side bar - i need it removed here. The issue is, both are product category pages

Comment: what i exactly needs is, which i realised now..My question is, Can i remove the sidebar only for particular URLs of my side.
If the url is like below - remove the side bar and make the page full width
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/
http://www.example.com/product-category/Faucet/

I dont want to remove the sidebar for "Product Category" reason, i want the side bar to show up for the below URLs:
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/closets/one-piece-closets/

Comment: Replace `if (!is_product_category())` at the bottom of your custom **archive-product.php** file with `if (!is_product_category('sanitaryware') && !is_product_category('Faucet'))`

Comment: For full-width: replace `if (is_product_category())` in the body_class filter of your **functions.php** file with `if (is_product_category('sanitaryware') || is_product_category('Faucet'))`

Comment: `if (!is_product_category('sanitaryware') && !is_product_category('Faucet'))` did not work.. the side bar is still showing on the page example.com/product-category/sanitaryware

Comment: My present code in the archive-product.php is `<?php
  /**
   * woocommerce_sidebar hook
   *
   * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
   */
   if (!is_product_category('sanitaryware') && !is_product_category('Faucet')) {
  do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
   }
 ?>`

Comment: Is the sidebar showing up on example.com/product-category/Faucet as well? If it's showing up on one of those Product Category pages, but not the other then I would think that the slug of one of the Product Categories isn't correct in the **archive-product.php** file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87698/discussion-between-john-franky-and-kory-northrop).

Comment: May i request you for chat ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the sidebar from category page override **archive-product.php** or use action hook in **function.php** in your current theme in WordPress.

Instead of editing these files directly within the plugin (which is a very bad idea because once update the plugin and all of your changes will be lost!), you can copy them into your theme:

- In your theme directory, make a new folder called “WooCommerce.”
- Navigate to the WooCommerce plugin directory and open the "templates" folder. The templates folder has a lot of subfolders with all of the different templates that WooCommerce uses. Fortunately, the template file structure and naming in WooCommerce is easy to follow.
- In your newly created "WooCommerce" folder, copy the template file that you want to edit.

> Remember to keep the directory structure the same here. If the
>   template you want to edit is within a subfolder then remember to
>   create that subfolder within your theme's directory.

In **archive-product.php** -

```
<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_sidebar hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');?>
```

this code display sidebar on category page remove this code and save file .

or

To remove sidebar from category page you want to use action hook in
   **function.php** file -

```
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'remove_sidebar' );
    function remove_sidebar()
    {
        if( is_product_category()) { 
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
       }
    }
```

Next, we have to edit the **style.css** in your theme folder-

```
body.product-category #content
    {
            width: 100%;
    }
```

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html